# Labeling rows and columns in python

Tags: python-3.x

I trying to  label  the header of a 10x10 python array
could you tell me what i´m doing wrong.
I need something like this:
[Board_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txOIS.jpg)

thanks in advance

```
Board=[]
rows= 10
columns= 10
for i in range (rows):
  Board.append([])
  for j in range (columns):
    Board[i].append(None)
for i in range(rows):
  for j in range (columns):
    Board[i][j] = 0
suma = 0
for i in range (rows):
  for j in range (columns):
     suma = suma + Board[i][j]
#print(Board,"Su suma es:", suma)
for i in range (rows):
  for j in range (columns):
    print(Board[i][j],end="  ")
  print("")
```

Comment: `could you tell me what i´m doing wrong`. Please can you be more specific? Which line is behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: Al the lines are working fine, but I need to add labels  both to rows and columns
I need that it looks like the  picture attached

Comment: Sounds like an interesting assignment. Unfortunately, most us require a question beyond "I need to do this" - if you can have a go, and tell us precisely where you get stuck, you might receive helpful responses.

Comment: Thank you very much
you´re very kind